# Dockerfile hide variables (user creation)

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to generate a docker image from Ubuntu 18.04.

To administrate the container I am creating a default user :

```
# set default user
RUN useradd -m docker && echo "docker:docker" | chpasswd && adduser docker sudo

USER docker
```

My problem is I would like to set a secured password on it, and my dockerfile is intended to be versioned with Git.

So my question is : is there a way to load variables in dockerfile from a .env file or anything else ?

I have seen an option on the docker run command, but not for the docker build, am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you write in the Dockerfile can be trivially retrieved in plain text with `docker history`.  Any file in the image can be very easily retrieved by anyone who can run any `docker` command.  There is no way around either limitation.

Do NOT try to set user passwords for your Docker images like this.  In most cases it shouldn't be necessary to formally "log in" to a container at all.  Let the container run the single application process it needs to run, and don't try to set up an ssh daemon, sudo, or other things you'd have in a more complete server environment.

(You shouldn't usually need a shell inside a container; you don't for other kinds of processes like your Nginx server, for example.  If you do, you can get one with `docker exec`, and if your main process runs as a non-root user, you can add a `-u root` option to be root in that shell.  Again, you can't prevent an end user from being able to do this.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, docker exec with -u root is what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a standalone container, then you can use a script with the variables and run `docker RUN`, or `ENTRYPOINT` to run the script. This would contain your password information, and then you can carry on with the build of your image.

If you are using Docker Swarm, you can use secrets, more information on the following link, and differences if you are using Windows or Linux are explained as well.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/